# Creating API for application interaction

Tags: web-services, api, rest, soap

We have an internal application. As time went on and new applications were requested, that exchange data between eachother, the interaction became bound to the database schema. Meaning changes in the database require changes everywhere else. As we plan to build even more applications that will depend on the same data this quickly will become and unmanagable mess.

Now i'm looking to abstract that interaction behind an API. Currently i have trouble choosing the right tool.

Interaction at times could be complex, meaning data is posted to one service and if the action has been completed it should notify the sender of that.

Another example would be that some data does not have context without the data from other services. Lets say there is one service for [Schools] and one for [Students]. So if the [School] gets deleted or changed the [Student] needs to be informed about it immeadetly and not when he comes to [School].

Advice? Suggestions? SOAP/REST/?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need an API. In my opinion you need an architecture which decouples your database from the domain logic and other parts of the application. Such an architecture is for example [clean architecture](http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html), [onion architecture](https://www.develop.com/onionarchitecture) and [hexagonal architecture](http://alistair.cockburn.us/Hexagonal+architecture) ([ports&adapters](http://www.dossier-andreas.net/software_architecture/ports_and_adapters.html) by new name). They share the same concepts, you have a domain logic, which does not depend from any framework, external lib, delivery method, data storage solutions, etc... This domain logic communicates with the outside world through adapters having well defined interfaces. If you first design the inside of your domain logic, and the interfaces of the adapters, and just after the outside components, then it is called [domain driven design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) (DDD).

So for example if you want to move from MySQL to MongoDB you already have a DataStorageInterface, and the only thing you need is writing a MongoDBAdapter which implements this interface, and ofc migrate the data...

To design the adapters you can use two additional concepts; command and query segregation (CQRS) and event sourcing (ES). CQRS is for connecting delivery methods like REST, SOAP, webapplications, etc... to the domain logic. For example you can raise a CreateUserCommand from your REST API. After that the proper listener in the domain logic processes that command, and by success it raises a domain event, like UserCreatedEvent. Your REST API can listen to that event and respond with a success message to the REST client. The UserCreatedEvent can be listened by one or more storage adapter too. So they can process that event and persist the new user. You don't necessary use only a single database. For example if a relational database is faster by a specific type of query, then you can use that, but if a noSQL database suites better to the job, then you can use that too. So you can use as many databases as you want for your queries, the only thing you need is writing a storage adapter for them. For example if your REST client wants to retrieve the profile of a specific user, then it can raise a GetUserProfileByIdQuery and the domain logic can ask the adapter of a database which can serve the query. After that the adapter can send for example an SQL query to a MySQL database and return the response. By ES you add EventStorage to your system, which stores the raised domain events. It can be very useful if you want to migrate your data from one query database to another. In that case you create a new storage adapter to your new database, and replay all of the domain events from the EventStorage in historical order to that adapter, so it can fill the new database with the relevant data. That's all, you don't have to write complicated migration scripts...

In your case I think your should create at least domain events, and use event sourcing. That will totally decouple your database from the other parts of your application. Adding a REST or SOAP API can have a similar effect, but building HTTP connections to access your database can slow down your application.